# problems in installation process of magento on mamp server

Tags: magento, mamp

Zend_Db_Statement_Exception Object
(
    [_previous:Zend_Exception:private] => 
    [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'importexport_importdata' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `importexport_importdata` (
.
.
.

Comment: i have redirect to this page in the middle of installation http://localhost:8888/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/  and content of this page is as above. how do i get out of this

Answer (score 0):

This is saying that some of your database tables already exist. If this is a new install and you have no data in the database, clear your database, and your /var/cache and /var/session folders. Then start the install again.